# Replicating minX and minY returned by a Path class in Fabric 1.x in 2.x

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Previously when creating a `Fabric.Path` in 1.x, the properties `minX` and `minY` were returned.

In 2.4.1 these values are not returned. There appears to me no mention of this removal in the migration docs. Whilst `minX` and `minY` are equivalent to `left` and `top` at the time of path initialisation, it appears as though the values cannot simply be swapped out. For example, the following function (the need for this function is explained here [FabricJS - When moving a path the 'path' object doesn't update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406351/fabricjs-when-moving-a-path-the-path-object-doesnt-update)) now does not work (and swapping `minX` to `left` and `minY` to `top` works when drawing the initial path but when updating it causes the path to 'snap' back to the original position).

```
transformedPoint = (target) => {
  const points = [];
  const path = target.path;
  points.push(new fabric.Point(path[0][1], path[0][2]));
  points.push(new fabric.Point(path[1][3], path[1][4]));
  points.push(new fabric.Point(path[1][1], path[1][2]));
  const matrix = target.calcTransformMatrix();
  return points
  .map(p => new fabric.Point(
    p.x - target.minX - (target.width / 2) - (target.strokeWidth / 2),
    p.y - target.minY - (target.height / 2) - (target.strokeWidth / 2)),
  )
  .map(p => fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix));
}
```

I have looked at the 1.7.19 source code to see how these values used to be calculated but I don't see how I can make use of `_parseDimensions()` in the code above as it is a private method?